# How to obtain all subsets of a list with repetition?

Tags: list-manipulation, subset

I'd like to generate all lists of length `m` containing all possible element combinations from a given list of length `n` with repetition. One way is to generate all tuples of the length `m`, then delete duplicates:

```
n = 5; m = 4;
Union[Sort /@ Tuples[Range[n], {m}]]
```

But already for $n=m=9$ it gives

> General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was
> insufficient memory available to complete the computation.

And `Subsets` command gives subsets with every element present only once, so I don't see how it can be used here.

Comment: For example: `n = 4;  m = 3;` and `t = Permutations[Range[n], {m}]` ?

Comment: @Syed no, `Permutations` uses every element once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mSubsets[n_, m_] := Sort[Join @@ 
  (Sort /@ IntegerPartitions[#, {m}, Range[n]] & /@ Range[m, n m])]

mSubsets[5, 3]
```

[image]

```
mSubsets[5, 4]
```

[image]

```
Length @ mSubsets[9, 9]
```

> ```
> 24310
> ```

Comment: Nice answer! Note, op (@Andrew), that to apply this to an arbitrary list, you can define `mSubsets[n_Integer, m_Integer] := <as above>` instead, and then define `mSubsets[l_List, m_Integer] := Part[l, #] & /@ mSubsets[Length[l], m]`. (Though there might be some speedup if you modify the original code cleverly instead, I'm not sure.)